# Monitor Cassandra Database Remotely using Application Manager 14

Tags: cassandra, datastax, jmx, jconsole, applicationmanager

Im having trouble monitoring a cassandra database that I have in a remote machine. I have already done the steps from: https://docs.datastax.com/en/ddacsecurity/doc/ddacsecurity/secureJmxAuthentication.html

However, I cant seem to connect to it using application manager or Jconsole.

My cassandra-env file is looking like this:

```
if [ "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" ]; then
    LOCAL_JMX=no
fi

# Specifies the default port over which Cassandra will be available for
# JMX connections.
# For security reasons, you should not expose this port to the internet.  Firewall it if needed.
JMX_PORT="7199"

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT"
  #sJVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.login.config=CassandraLogin"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-jaas.config"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.authorizer=org.apache.cassandra.auth.jmx.AuthorizationProxy"
else
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
  # if ssl is enabled the same port cannot be used for both jmx and rmi so either
  # pick another value for this property or comment out to use a random port (though see CASSANDRA-7087 for origins)
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=cseetprj03.essex.ac.uk"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false"
  # turn on JMX authentication. See below for further options
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.login.config=CassandraLogin"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-jaas.config"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.authorizer=org.apache.cassandra.auth.jmx.AuthorizationProxy"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.access"

  # jmx ssl options
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=<enabled-protocols>"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites=<enabled-cipher-suites>"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<keystore-password>"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore"
  #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<truststore-password>"
fi
```

I decided to not use authentication because it is within a secure network.

It is worth mentioning that I also have a cassandra database running (on the same machine where my monitoring tool is) and is also being monitored.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do `ps -aef` on the Cassandra process to check that options are applied... Also, having no authentication is a bad idea - JMX is used not only for monitoring, but for other operations as well, so it's even possible to truncate your tables remotely

Comment: you mean ps -aef (PID of cassandra process running in port 7199)?

Comment: yes, that's process...